# In R, Aggregate() function by id, setting columns as number of values, not the values themselves

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, reshape

I have a dataset that has household ID ('id') and fuel economy of vehicles owned by the household ('mpg'). This is in long form, with only the two columns 'id' and 'mpg'.

I am trying to use either the aggregate() function or ddply() to apply the following function to the data:

```
logratio <- function(data=x, mpg=mpg)
{
    if (length(data[mpg])>1) {
        ratio <- log(max(data[mpg])/min(data[mpg]))
        return(ratio)
    }
    else return(0)
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
mpgdf <- aggregate(mpg~id, FUN=logratio, data=mpgdata)
```

and

```
df <- ddply(mpgdata,~id,logratio)
```

Neither work.

The key here is that my theoretical wide format would be an 'id' column with one row for each id, and then columns for the mpg of each vehicle up to the maximum number of vehicles (ie if the house with the most vehicles has three vehicles, 'mpg1, 'mpg2', 'mpg3'). And I would like to find the natural log of the ratio of the highest fuel economy to the smallest, returning 0 (log of 1) if there is only one vehicle.

I'm starting to get a bit frustrated as both plyr and reshape seem to want to set columns as the values of the extant 'mpg' column, whereas I would like them as explained above.

I would like this be returned as a dataframe with two columns - 'id' with each of the household IDs a single time set against 'mpglogratio', so that I can then merge that back into a larger dataset I have.

And help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `plyr` you can try this

```
logratio <- function(x)
        log(max(x)/min(x))

require(plyr)
mtcars <- mtcars[,c("cyl", "mpg")]
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, c(5, 30))

ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, mpglogratio = logratio(mpg))
##   cyl mpglogratio
## 1   4     0.46002
## 2   5     0.00000
## 3   6     0.18419
## 4   8     0.61310
```

Just replace `cyl` by `id` and `mtcars` with your actual data to make it work with your data and actually there's no need to test for the length because if your mpg is of length one then `max == min` thus `max/min == 1` so you'll end up with `log(1)` also known as `0`

A final note, if you want to merge it back quickly, use `transform` instead of `summarise` like this

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), transform, mpglogratio = logratio(mpg))
```